# How do you get different Soc. M thumbnails for different routes in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, linkedin-api, meta

I have an Angular page `www.title.org` running via AWS Cloudfront.

This project has some meta information in the `index.html` file, like:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Bla bla" />
<meta property="og:image" content="image.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="www.title.org" />
```

However when I post `www.title.org/quiz` in social media I want there to be a different thumbnail than `image.png` in the preview.

I have attempted using [Angular Meta](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta) in my `quiz.component.ts` file:

```
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:title', content: 'Title' })
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:description', content: 'New description' })
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:image', content: 'image_2.png' })
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:url', content: 'www.title.org/quiz' })
```

but this doesn't change the thumbnail or anything else for that matter.

How do you change thumbnails depending on what route you are linking to for an Angular page?

Update: I attempted create a new index file, with different meta data and a redirect. So in `quiz/index.html` I have:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta property="og:title" content="My quiz" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Do the quiz" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="image_2.png" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.title.org/quiz" />
    ...
</head>

<body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "https://www.styreskolen.org/quiz";
    </script>
</body>
```

So if I post `https://www.styreskolen.org/quiz/index.html` I should get the new meta data, but no such luck. It does however work on Skype, so it almost seems like LinkedIn just doesn't care what I do, and just wants to look at my root code.

Comment: does an removeTag/addTag what you want to achieve ? or does it also not change the tumbnails. if it does the updateTag method just isnt correct. if it doesnt change aswell, you atleast know it isnt a problem with the methods.

Comment: No, because I want the meta data to exist before I even enter the page. So when I link to the URL and it should present as a box with all the meta data. Either way removeTag/addTag doesn't do anything.

Comment: Metadata aren’t displayed on the page but are machine parsable. Meta elements are typically used to specify the page description, keywords, author, last modified, and other metadata. The metadata can be used by browsers (how to display content or reload the page), search engines (keywords), or other web services. Meta tags play an important role in SEO.

Comment: I did try `this.meta.removeTag('image');` then `this.meta.addTag({ name: 'image', content: 'image_2.png' })`, in the `quiz.component.ts`, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in the end my way to solve this was to create a separate bucket with a Cloudfront distribution with its own domain name `www.quiz.title.org` that only contained an `index.html` file redirecting you to `www.title.org/quiz` and the meta data that I wanted.